# jquery duplicate items when append values to multi select

Tags: php, jquery

I'm facing a problem when I append values to multi select, Im working on laravel and modal so I will be able to add and edit in the same page, for create or add there is foreach which gets all values in the multiselect, on edit item, I append selected data using jquery but in this point it selects the value but in the same time showing the value if I wanted to select more so I have duplicated items

**blade:**

```
      <select class="form-control select2" id="permission"  name="permission[]" multiple="multiple">
                  @foreach($permissions as $key => $value)
                       <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>
                 @endforeach
      </select>
```

**jquery:**

```
  $(response.permissions).each(function (i,value) {
  $("#permission").append("<option value='"+value['id']+"' selected>"+value['name']+"</option>");
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

is because you are looping through the permissions and using append, to solve it you can just change the prop selected if you are looping the options with the each method like this:

```
$(response.permissions).each(function (i,value) {
     $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

if you are looping the selected tags you need to make some modifications in the selector:

```
$(response.permissions).each(function (i,value) {
    $(`#permission option[value='${value}']`).prop('selected', true);
});
```

check here another example, if you are using select2 you just need to add tags=true to make the crud in your tags box

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#permission').select2({
    tags: true});
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width: 100%">
  <select class="form-control select2" id="permission" name="permission[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Hello Country</option>
    <option value="2">Hello World</option>
    <option value="3">Hello Stack Overflow</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ok this is will empty the select box, so if the edit was for one value then it will shows only this value, but I want to keep the foreach and select if the value equal what in the list

Comment: Check now, you can mark the option in the loop as selected with "prop" method

Comment: nothing happned!! do I have to update something?

Comment: Yes, if you check in the second example if you are looping the tags selected you need to add the selector based on the option values.

Comment: it became more complicated, I can't get what I should do!!! do I have to add ${value} in this way! or as mine is value['id']

Comment: if I tried this to check alert(${value}); it doesn't show any thing!!!\

Comment: in your case if you control the duplicate values in your tags box is not a problem the filter  because it will match with the selected value, another way is to add a data-* tag with HTML and use as a selector

Comment: is because the ${} is to inject the string, is the same like common concatenation for example "one " + value, you need to use the alert like this: alert(value) to test

Comment: hopefully you can make the solution more clear and able to apply

Comment: I added the example of how you activate the add and remove functionality in the select2 by activating the parameter tags, I hope that is what are you look for.

Comment: thank you very much but I think you didn't get my problem!!! im using foreach in blade and when I use jquery to edit row, it works fine but it shows the data selected twice

Comment: is because blade already add the value and you are looping again and adding with jquery using append, you don't need to create the loop with jquery again because the select2 library brings the functionality already

Comment: ok good so how can I show the selected items in this loop using jquery!

Comment: lets consider that 2 items of 4 items were selected, I wana show those 2 when I click somewhere using jquery

Comment: please helppppppppppppp

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
    var  selected_value = [];
    i = 0;
    $(response.permissions).each(function (i,value) {
        selected_value[i++] = value['id'];
     });

   $('#permission').select2().val(selected_value).trigger('change');
    },
```